# how to get the "old picture" effect in openCV?

Tags: c, opencv

I am new in opencv. I am trying to make an application to transform an image to an "old picture" effect. can anybody help me with the algorithm? or is there any sample code for this? I am using C language...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Image transformations, including converting to sepia ("old picture" style), can be accomplished using [matrix operations](http://www.graficaobscura.com/matrix/index.html).

**EDIT**: A different transformation called "grain effect" can be accomplished by drawing on each frame:

1. White specs of dust at random locations about the x- and y- axis,
2. A white bar that spans the whole height of the frame at a random x-axis location, and;
3. A circular flicker spanning out from the center of the frame of a random intensity.

[This](http://www.republicofcode.com/tutorials/flash/old_grain/) is a good tutorial for a flash-based version. Just translate what's done there into C.

Comment: sepia is not exactly an "old picture" effect. there is one more effect that i found... "old movie" effect. how to achieve that?

Comment: Edited the post and added another option for "Grain effect". Check out Wikipedia to learn about film grain for more about it.