# Any opencv library intended for image effects only

Tags: image, image-processing, opencv

Is there any open source library available meant for image filtering effects(like fisheye, old movie etc.), based on opencv library. If you refer to any book/site on opencv which will be helpful for this purpose, I will be extremely grateful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't any based on OpenCV, because this is not the purpose of OpenCV. On the other hand, a very popular library for this is [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php).

ImageMagick comprises a set of tools to to create, edit, compose, or convert images, but it also provides a C++ API through [Magick++](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/magick++.php?ImageMagick=d9o31nc5od1arolsvn5cjnci84), which is what you should take a look at.

I also suggest you check [Fred's ImageMagick Scripts](http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/mottle/index.php) for a list of several effects that were easily achieved using ImageMagick tools.

Comment: Thanks, Imagemagick will be much useful at least in this case. The reason I want to use opencv is that, my application have also face detection feature. Lot of example already available in opencv regarding this. I can use both, but it will be great if I achieve all effects easily using opencv alone.

Comment: OpenCV was not designed for image effects and a lot is missing to achieve this task easily. I believe a mix of OpenCV-ImageMagick is what you should use to do the job.

Answer (score 1):

Read Gary Bradsky's ["Learning OpenCV"](http://books.google.co.in/books?id=seAgiOfu2EIC&dq=isbn:0596516134&redir_esc=y). It has details about fisheye distortion. Or checkout [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1927145/how-to-simulate-fisheye-lens-effect-by-opencv), which also deals with fisheye effect and its simulation. Old picture effect is explained in [this SO.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5699297/how-to-get-the-old-picture-effect-in-opencv)